# Can i browse file stored on Remote server through simple <input type="file"> control in asp.net MVC 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, filebrowse

I have a file control of HTML  <input type="file">

And i want to browse file from the remote server.

I want to locate a file which is **stored on remote server**.

**For eg.** If my website is hosted on http://192.168.56.116

and if there is a folder on server http://192.168.56.116/UploadedFiles

then i should be able to browse files contained in that folder.

**Is this thing is possible in asp.net MVC 2.0 ???**

Please suggest me any alternative or solution for this problem.

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: The native `<input type="file">` element is only for uploading files. It will not let you browse files in the server.

Comment: @Alex R. - Hey thanks for the reply.
Is there any other control through which i can perform same thing???

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish anyway? Are you trying to select a file from the same server then upload the same to it? What do you plan to do with the selected file in the server?

Comment: @AlexR. i want to locate the file of the remote server as a FILENAME in my website so by which i can access and read the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do it.

You should use special web file browser - for example, CKFinder. http://ckfinder.com/

Comment: Hey thanks,
Is this free to use ?
looks like it will solve my problem
Thank you very much.

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't. I found a several free projects - http://freewebfilemanager.com/filemanager/ or http://webfilebrowser.sourceforge.net/. But I didn't use them, so I can't advice anything

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via IIS ..

**Its not advised** but its possible, you simply need to enable directory browsing in IIS.

Just be careful as anyone can view the contents of the directory unless you password protect it.